# get books read by friends using facebook api

Tags: facebook, api

the facebook profile of a user contains the user likes in form of movies,books,television etc. I want these details for a user's friend.For eg, if B is a friend of A, then the books read by B should be displayed when one logs in the app.

Answer (score 0):

> The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now
>   limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Facebook also removed all friend permissions, so you will not get the books of the friends in any case. This is mostly for privacy reasons.